# help to construct grep output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a command I am using

```
#cat test |grep "Ongoing Calls" |awk -F' ' '{print $3}'
40
2
```

As you can see it returns 2 values 40 & 2

I want to now add these together and put into a file as 42

any ideas

edit here is what is in the test file - all I want is the values in OnGoing calls and sumed together

```
    Iedge Group                                               1
    RasIpAddr                                                 0.0.0.0/0
    SubnetIP
    SubnetMask
    Max Calls                                                 50 (0:-1)
    Max 911 Overflow Calls                                    0 (0:0)
    Ongoing Calls                                             2 (0:2)
    Ongoing Calls                                             40 (40:0)
    Max Src Hunting                                           0
    Max number of simultaneously allowed transfer calls       0
    Ongoing transfer calls                                    0
    Priority                                                  0
    Call Duration                                             0
    Idle TCP/TLS/SCTP Connection Timeout                               0
    Bi-directional TCP/SCTP connections                            enabled
    Capabilities                                              gateway
    SIP                                                       enabled
    H323                                                      disabled
    Zone
```

when I used this command

```
    awk '/Ongoing Calls/ { sum += 3 } END { print sum }' test `
```

I keep getting the value 3 if there is nothing in the OnGoing calls section

Comment: you can do it all in awk. Also show what is in test. Also format your question.

Comment: ok, formatting updated... (sorry first time using stackexchange) - can you give me advice on how to do it all in awk? thanks

Comment: show what is in test

Comment: the file is long so ill just pull the relevant info out

Comment: Please post it in the question formatted. Yes a sample is all that is needed.

Comment: @123 in this case, the contents of the file is irrelevant. The issue is about summing the values of column 3 of the output from the `grep` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda Making the best solution is not irrelevant, surely it's better to write good code instead of patching peoples bad code.

Comment: @123 Well, the best solution in this case, as in many other cases, would be to have whatever created the input file also create the output of the sums into another file (i.e. to solve the problem even before having to `grep` through the output). Here, we know two things: we have two numbers, we want to add them together.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's ridiculous to expect whatever created the file to do post processing. And no we don't, we clearly have a file with content in it, and OP wants numbers from that file adding together. The fact that they have strung together a bad command to begin with doesn't mean you have to use it.

Comment: @123 Very true, I agree. I was only replying to the OP's question as per title and text "how do I add together these two numbers *coming out of `grep`*". In *many* other cases, I've seen users ask how to parse extremely complicated files for complex data. The best solution there is to produces the data in a more manageable format (by only exporting the needed information, by changing the output format, or by aggregating the data in some way, depending on the situation).

Comment: sorry I added some more detail to help me construct the best command

Comment: The thing you copied from my answer contains a typo that I have corrected in the answer. The `sum += 3` should be `sum += $3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `awk` script to

```
awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }'
```

As user @123 points out, the whole pipeline may be replaced with a single call to `awk`:

```
awk '/Ongoing Calls/ { sum += $3 } END { print sum }' test
```

Comment: missing `/Ongoing Calls/`

Comment: this worked, I just tested it

Comment: @123 if you want to replace the call to `grep` too, yes. If not, then it's not needed.

Comment: Why would you not want to replace the call to grep...

Comment: @123 I didn't say I didn't want to, I was only answering the OP's question about how to sum the values that `grep` produced.

Comment: @Kusalananda You said `if you want to replace the call to grep too`, which is obviously the correct thing to do instead of forking pointless processes, needlessly using cat and piping together redundant commands.

Comment: @123 Ok ok, I'm updating...

Comment: actually ive made some changed to the orignal question as the command shows 3 when there is zero data in the test file.

Comment: @WMK83 Sorry, that's an obvious typo on my part. Will fix it immediately. There should be a `$` in front of that `3`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is better than using `awk`:

```
sed -rn 's/Ongoing Calls *([0-9]+).*/\1/p' test | paste -sd+ | bc
```